# Connect Accu-Chek Performa Nano device Via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can I Connect Accu-Chek Performa Nano device from Android Smart Phones through Bluetooth?

Comment: if the `Accu-Chek Performa Nano` has a bluetooth, then you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no Bluetooth in Accu-chek Perfoma nano**,Your have to Place device in communication mode by connecting the device to the computer using a USB cable or an Accu-Chek IR-to-USB cable. (The IR-to-USB cable enables compatible devices to send and receive data via a wireless connection.)